# Karate - response cookies not being passed automatically to the next request

Tags: karate

When I'm calling first request form different feature file, the response cookies of first request has not being passed to next request
Below is my code:

```
##First request##
Given def createUserResponsePayload = call
read('classpath:helper/bi/createBiAccount.feature@createBiUser')

## Second request##
    * def updateBIAccountNegativeRequestPayload = read('classpath:data/atg/payload/bi/updateBIAccount.json')
    * set updateBIAccountNegativeRequestPayload.!gender = 'female'
    Given path '/v1/bi/account'
    When request updateBIAccountNegativeRequestPayload
    When method PUT
    Then status 200
```

Currently we are using below work around, @PeterThomas could you suggest if you have any better solution?

```
And cookie JSESSIONID = createUserResponsePayload.responseCookies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. It is your responsibility to pass variables and responses.

If you use "shared scope" you may not have to do this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#shared-scope